# Call a function outside a class

Tags: php, wordpress

This is a part of code that involved in my question:

```
class My_Box {
  function __construct( $args ) {
    add_action( 'admin_footer', array( __CLASS__, 'add_templates' ) );
  }
  static function add_templates() {
    self::add_template( 'list' );
    self::add_template( 'grid' );
  }
  private static function add_template( $name ) {
    echo html('script',array( /*args*/));
  }
}
```

The add_action in the above code requires the arguments to be string like this:

```
add_action('handle','function_name');
```

Now I need to run the add_action statement outside the class, I figured something like this:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', My_Box::add_templates() );
```

This statement got a debug message of "Notice: Undefined offset: 0 ".

How to code this add_action statement correctly?

Comment: `add_action('wp_footer',array("My_Box","add_templates"));`?

Comment: That's not going to work OUTSIDE a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The array you are passing as the second argument to `add_action` is a callback.  The first value in the array is the class name and the second is the name of a static method on that class.  Within a class `__CLASS__` will contain the name of that class.  So to make this same call elsewhere you just need to replace that with the actual class name, e.g.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', array('My_Box', 'add_templates' );
```

For more info on how callbacks are defined see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Answer (score 1):

for fetching in class

```
add_action('handle', array(get_class(), 'function_name'));
```

outside of class

```
add_action('handle', array('class_name', 'func_name'));
```

Comment: `get_class()` and `__CLASS__` are equivalent here

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action#Using_add_action_with_a_class

To use the add_action hook when your plugin or theme is built up using classes, add $this to your add_action call together with the function name within that class, like so:

```
class MyPluginClass
{
    public function __construct()
    {
         //add your actions to the constructor!
         add_action( 'save_post', array( $this, 'myplugin_save_posts' ) );
    }

    public function myplugin_save_posts()
    {
         //do stuff here...
    }
}
```